# White bar below navigation bar in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using one of the bootstrap templates and although I have set `margin-bottom:0`, I am still having a problem with the navigation bar and the white bar. Whenever I run this code, a white bar appears below the navigation bar and then the content. Is there a way to remove the white bar? Here's the html code:

```css
    @charset "utf-8";
    /* CSS Document */
    * {
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
    .navbar {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
    }
    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {
        height: 450px
    }
    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 20px;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
        background-color: #555;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    
    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .row.content {
        height: auto;
    }
    }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <title>index</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
      
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">    
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
          <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
          <h1>Welcome</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
          <hr>
          <h3>Test</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
          <div class="well">
            <p>ADS</p>
          </div>
          <div class="well">
            <p>ADS</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
      <p>Footer Text</p>
    </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Looks like you have included bootstrap.css after your style changes. Either change the order, or put !important on .navbar eg. .navbar  { margin-bottom : 0 !important }

Comment: @sheavens Thank you so much! I didn't know that implementation order was important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User !important with margin bottom because margin bottom already define in bootstrap css that's why sometime custom css not work.

.navbar{
 margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have included bootstrap.css after your style changes. Either change the order, or put !important on your margin-bottom. 
Best practice is to apply your styles in the correct order. The last defined style will take precedence.